# Are compact operators trace class operators?

Tags: banach-algebras

We say that $A\in B(\mathcal{H})$ is a trace class operator, if
 $\sum_{i\in I}\langle|A|e_i,e_i\rangle<\infty$,$\hspace{0.1cm}$ such that {$e_i; i\in I$} is a orthonormal bass for Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

If compact operator on Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ is a trace class operator ?

Answer (score 3):

No. For example, say $$Ax=\sum\lambda_n\langle x,e_n\rangle e_n,$$where $(e_n)$ are orthomormal and $\lambda_n$ are scalars. Then $A$ is compact if $\lambda_n\to0$, while $A$ is trace class requires $\sum|\lambda_n|<\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the opposite direction is ture.$\renewcommand{\l}[1]{\lVert #1\rVert}\def \yb{\frac{1}{2}}$

Suppose $u$ is a positive trace class operator and $\{e_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in\Gamma}$ is a basis of $H$,
    then $\forall\varepsilon>0,$ there exists a finite subset $\Gamma_0$ of $\Gamma$ such that 
    \begin{equation*}
 \lvert\sum_{\alpha\in \Gamma_0}\langle u e_\alpha,e_\alpha\rangle-\l{u}_1\rvert <\varepsilon,
 \end{equation*}
    i.e.$\newcommand{\Tr}{\operatorname{trace}}$
    \begin{equation*}
 \lvert\Tr(p)-\Tr(u)\rvert<\varepsilon,
 \end{equation*}
    where
    \begin{equation*}
 p=\sum_{\alpha\in \Gamma_0}u^\yb e_\alpha\otimes e_\alpha u^\yb
 \end{equation*}
    is a finite-rank operator on $H$.
    Note that $\l{p-u}\leq\l{p-u}_1=\Tr(\lvert u-p\rvert)=\Tr(u-p), $ so $u\in K(H)$.

Answer (score 0):

No. Compact, positive definite operators, for example, are trace class if and only if their eigenvalues are summable